# What is the correct method of installing Private IP With SSL Certificate Signed by broker from DigiCert

Tags: php, nginx, curl, https

I am connected to a vendor (for accessing their API) through a NAT. I can easily access the APIs through http, now for production, https is required.  However, when I make the API request to the vendor's endpoint with https enabled, below is the errors:

When SSL Verification is enabled:

**cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz:18423/interface//request**

When SSL Verification is disabled:

**cURL Error #:OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading, errno 0**

I have taken the following steps to set up the SSL.

**Step 1:** I have first generated the SSL Certificate request and private key with openssl as below:-

-

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mycompany.key -out mycompany.csr
```

N**OTE:** The FQDN used api.mycompany.com does not exist. My server is accessed through my private IP address within the network only. (The vendor can reach me for a callback through the NAT)

**Step 2:** I have sent the CSR only to the vendor to sign

**Step 3:** Vendor signed the request and sent back the following files:

1.mydomain.cer

2.mydomain.p7b

3.broker_vendor_com.crt

4.DigiCertCA.crt

**Step 4:** I have decoded the mydomain.cer
I Followed [Nginx: Create CSR & Install SSL Certificate (OpenSSL)](https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/nginx-openssl.htm#ssl_certificate_install)

**Step 5:** I combined the mydomain.cer and DigitCert.cer into new file bundle.crt

**Step 6:** I added the bundle.crt and mycompany.key into my nginx server as below

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/salaammfbank.key;
```

I tried disabling the verification and I get the errors stated above. When I make normal curl request on the terminal using

```
curl -kv https://xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz:18423/interface//request
```

I can reach the endpoint with valid response status 200.

Below is the php curl request that returns

**cURL Error #:OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading, errno 0**

and when verification is enabled

**cURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

```
$url = 'https://xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz:18423/interface//request';

$body = '';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 40,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/xml"]
]);

#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

What am I missing to be able to reach the vendor endpoints through https from my server?

Comment: I access quite a few APIs over HTTPS using cURL, but I've never had to create a certificate. The only difference with the HTTP code is the addition of `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`.

Comment: Where are you setting the SSL options for your curl request?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware they send some callback to my server, and they require only through https in production environment.

Comment: OK, I get it. Yes, in that case you do need a SSL certificate.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius to see if disabling the verification of the certificates can go through with the request. but it is still not going through.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. Don't you just need a web server, and a domain with a SSL certificate? This is separate from the cURL request. Note that you, as far as I know, cannot get a SSL certificate for an IP address.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware My server is reached through NAT IP address that is masking my private IP, the certificated was generated with FQDN that does exist in my company, and endpoints are through IP addresses instead of domain names.  for example 

my endpoint: https://123.456.789
Vendor :   https://987.654.321

Comment: There is a lot that is unclear to me: *The FQDN used api.mycompany.com does not exist*; I don't see that used anywhere so I don't understand what this is referring to. *My server is accessed through my private IP address within the network only.* What server? I thought you were connected to the vendor using curl, which means you are the client side of that connection, not the server. So I don't understand what's connecting to what. *The vendor can reach me for a callback through the NAT*; how is that possible?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk As I understand it Noor does indeed use cURL to call the API, but then the API wants to call his/her web servers. This could, for instance, be used to implement [a webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook). The web server is located behind a NAT and uses a FQDN (fully qualified domain name) for which the certificate is needed. So, the web server should serve that certificate.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: Thank you. So we have conceptually 3 devices: the device making the cURL call, which is an HTTPS client; the vendor device, which is an HTTPS server when receiving the cURL request and HTTPS client when calling back to his web server; and his web server, which is an HTTPS server. If so that's a fairly complicated flow.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, it is indeed complicated. Moreso, I'm not sure where the cURL error occurs. Is it in the cURL call that Noor makes, or the one that the vendor makes back to the server of Noor? I think it is the latter, why else talk about making the certificate?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk and KIKOSoftware, see the answer I have posted. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

After a long weekend of trying to figure this out, I was able to hit the vendor endpoint through laravel Http facade to make the request and disabled the verification.

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
            'verify' => false,
        ])->withBody($this->ParseCreateTransactionXml($data),'text/xml')->post($url);
```

I have also tested with, and returned expected response using below curl:-

```
 $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->ParseCreateTransactionXml($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 2);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have not made any other changes in the rest of the code. I am not so sure why the code in the question was not working.